# how can i use filter function () to find a number bigger then k in a list

Tags: python, filter

how can I modify my code below to find the biggest number using filters () and not using list comprehension?

```
test_list = [2,3,5,6,8,9,10,16,17,] 
k = 5
print ("The list : " + str(test_list))
count = len([i for i in test_list if i > k])

print ("The numbers greater than 5 : " + str(count))
```

Comment: when you format for code, instead of using a "`", use 4 spaces in front of each line of code.

Comment: `f = filter(lambda x: x > 5, test_list)` will return a `filter` object containing all values of `test_list` that are greater than `5`. Not too sure what else you are looking for in an answer as your question is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first answer is:

The listcomp is good. If you don't want to make a temporary `list`, a generator expression (genexpr) is a perfectly fine alternative:

```
count = sum(1 for i in test_list if i > k)
```

That's not using the `filter` function, but that's because using the `filter` function when the predicate isn't a built-in implemented in C is a pessimization, and an ugly one, relative to using an equivalent listcomp or genexpr. But if you absolutely must, the options are:

```
count = len(list(filter(lambda i: i > k, test_list)))
# or
count = len(list(filter(k.__lt__, test_list)))
# or without filter, but also saving a list:
count = sum(map(k.__lt__, test_list))
```

`k.__lt__` is the bound method equivalent to testing `k < THEARGUMENT`, and it returns `True`/`False`, which is equivalent to 1/0 for math purposes, which is what lets the `sum` of the result of `map` work. If you absolutely need speed, using `k.__lt__` is the only way `filter`/`map` *might* be faster than the equivalent listcomp/genexpr; using a `lambda` that the listcomp/genexpr avoids basically guarantees it will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this ?

```
randomList = [2,3,5,6,8,9,10,16,17]
k=3
filteredList = filter(lambda x: x >k, randomList)
```

Comment: but it will just return the filtered numbers and not count of the filtered numbers

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answer if you find it helpful good luck